# Change width with @media (min-width:XXXXpx) Responsive ads

Tags: html, css, media, ads

Sorry for the confusing title.. I am not sure that its possible to do this, but if you have another way please be my guest.

```
.top-widget {
 width: 75.5%; <-------------- This is the correct width that i want to have.
 padding: 0 3px 0 0;
 border: none;
 background: none;
 }
```

But when i reach a certain pixel i want to change the width and keep it that way below 800px.

```
@meda (min-width:800px)   { .top.widget { width: 55.%; } } <-- This gives everything 55% (Also abow 800px)
@media (min-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px;  } }
@media (min-width:1024px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
@media (min-width:1300px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
@media (min-width:1700px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
```

This is so that the ads looks awesome on tablets also.

Comment: `@meda` != `@media`... fix your typo or copy/paste *exactly* what code you're trying to work with.

Comment: Please clarify your question more

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width` instead of `min-width`, so the media query is used below the specified screen width

In your case :

```
@media (max-width:800px)   { .top.widget { width: 55.%; } } 
@media (max-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px;  } }    
@media (max-width:1024px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }    
@media (max-width:1300px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }    
@media (max-width:1700px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
```

Comment: Thanks Robin!

It worked perfect! Have an extra awesome week! 
Cheers!